# How to test rest end point which accepts XML input using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I need to perform a load test to test one of the rest end point which accepts XML input using JMeter. how this can be achieved using JMeter(Which sampler I should use, what configurations ? ...etc I need to make)?. Earlier I have tested rest end points by inputting JSON input.

In Jmeter how can I change input as 'XML'instead of Json.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTTP Request Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to test end point which accepts XML input.
Select Body Data and add your XMl file in the section
Make sure you mention content type as XML in the child [Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) of HTTP Request
[image]

You can select type of  Method POST/GET/PUT.. in the method drop down
If you can access API from browser you can capture it with JMeter using proxy
For more information on running JMeter test please follow [this link..](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-recording/)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html) chapter of the [JMeter User Manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html) you can stick to the same way as you do for REST/JSON, use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler for sending the request.

You will also need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to send headers like [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) and [`SOAPAction`](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/java-soa-cookbook/9780596156091/ch05s10.html).